# Devel : what kind of information devel_boot, devel_shutdown and php tweak describes?

Tags: debugging

I have a problem on my website about slow query and many 324 errors.
I tried to resolve them but as i'm new in Drupal i have a lot of difficulties to understand some stuff.

(The website site i'm making actually have 102 modules install, 9 differents roles and a lot of permission on fields, node etc. We don't have a dedicated server so it's very slow and not optimize)

So i tried to do my best and i'm actually working with devel to see if i can do something maybe.

I read this about devel_shutdown on [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/871602) but as a beginner i'm not really sure to understand the meaning and the purpose of this function.
So i would like to know more about some function used by devel like:

- devel_boot
- php peak
- devel_shutdown

(devel_shudown = memory_allocated per user? and php peak = memory allocated by the server?)

As you see in my picture, i have a devel_shutdown greater than 41mo (sometimes more than 51mo). For people who worked on Drupal since many years do you think it's normal for a drupal site or do i have to be worried about that?

[image: devel module]

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **[devel_boot](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/devel_boot/7)** is the memory in use during hook_boot. It is the amount of memory Drupal is using just getting bootstrapped and ready
  to run module and theme code.
- **php peak** is the maximum amount of memory in use during your page request. It is provided by the PHP function
  [memory_get_peak_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php). This is probably the most important metric to consider.
- **[devel_shutdown](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/devel_shutdown/7)** is the memory in use at the last possible moment it can be measured with code in a request. It is registered
  via [drupal_register_shutdown_function()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_register_shutdown_function/7) which registers functions to be called once all other PHP code has finished executing.

Memory is important to monitor, but it doesn't seem like you are having issues with memory use. I can see from your screenshot that you are using 42MB of memory - that is nothing to be concerned about in most cases.

I would be more concerned about your slow cache queries (highlighted red in your screenshot). Try and figure out why they are taking so long to run.

There are a lot of resources on the web and drupal.org on improving performance. The biggest wins will come from caching and improving SQL performance - then you can start honing in on code profiling to figure out where your time is best spent.

Some resources that may help:

- [Performance articles on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/326504)
- [Tuning mysql](http://drupal.org/node/51263)
- [Presentation at Drupalcon London](http://london2011.drupal.org/conference/sessions/damn-quick-drupal-how-make-drupal-perform-and-scale-rockstar)

Best of luck!

Comment: Thxs for your answer. I happy to hear that 42mo isn't really a problem. For the cache i'm limited because i can't install apc or memcache on my server. But i saw an interesting module in your second link (db maintenance) i will see if i can optimize my database.Thxs again